# Remove Orphans site collections inside my content database raised the following:- Exception calling "Repair" with "1" argument(s)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, site-collection, content-database, orphan

I run the product configuration wizard on my SharePoint server 2013, after a hot fix installation:-

```
psconfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force
```

but i received the following exceptions, mainly that there are many orphans site collections:-

```
02/10/2016 01:10:16.35  OWSTIMER (0x0D64)   0x0C04  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxkz   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content  6dae5d9d-cc17-d003-e007-3995887e71c6
02/10/2016 01:10:16.35  OWSTIMER (0x0D64)   0x0C04  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxkz   ERROR   Database [WSS_Content] contains a site (Id = [70293d27-db5b-4f14-a2a7-cf089ffaf573], Url = [/kb/CustomerServiceKB]) that is not found in the site map. Consider detach and reattach the database.   6dae5d9d-cc17-d003-e007-3995887e71c6
02/10/2016 01:10:16.46  OWSTIMER (0x0D64)   0x0C04  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk0   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content  6dae5d9d-cc17-d003-e007-3995887e71c6
02/10/2016 01:10:16.46  OWSTIMER (0x0D64)   0x0C04  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk0   WARNING The orphaned sites could cause upgrade failures. Try detach and reattach the database which contains the orphaned sites. Restart upgrade if necessary.  6dae5d9d-cc17-d003-e007-3995887e71c6
02/10/2016 01:10:16.49  OWSTIMER (0x0D64)   0x0C04  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxkz   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content  6dae5d9d-cc17-d003-e007-3995887e71c6
02/10/2016 01:10:16.49  OWSTIMER (0x0D64)   0x0C04  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxkz   ERROR   Database [WSS_Content] contains a site (Id = [016ffbd0-7d5a-469d-83c5-e9b67dbb2ba3], Url = [/kb/customerservice]) that is not found in the site map. Consider detach and reattach the database. 6dae5d9d-cc17-d003-e007-3995887e71c6
02/10/2016 01:10:16.52  OWSTIMER (0x0D64)   0x0C04  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk0   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content  6dae5d9d-cc17-d003-e007-3995887e71c6
02/10/2016 01:10:16.52  OWSTIMER (0x0D64)   0x0C04  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk0   WARNING The orphaned sites could cause upgrade failures. Try detach and reattach the database which contains the orphaned sites. Restart upgrade if necessary.  6dae5d9d-cc17-d003-e007-3995887e71c6
02/10/2016 01:10:16.55  OWSTIMER (0x0D64)   0x0C04  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk3   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content  6dae5d9d-cc17-d003-e007-3995887e71c6
02/10/2016 01:10:16.55  OWSTIMER (0x0D64)   0x0C04  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk3   ERROR   Database [WSS_Content] contains a site (Id = [70293d27-db5b-4f14-a2a7-cf089ffaf573], Url = [/kb/CustomerServiceKB]) whose url is already used by a different site, in database (Id = [2611b773-88bc-4cc8-bebb-aa3cd238bc22], name = [WSS_Content]), in the same web application. Consider deleting one of the sites which have conflicting urls.    6dae5d9d-cc17-d003-e007-3995887e71c6
02/10/2016 01:10:16.58  OWSTIMER (0x0D64)   0x0C04  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk4   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content  6dae5d9d-cc17-d003-e007-3995887e71c6
02/10/2016 01:10:16.58  OWSTIMER (0x0D64)   0x0C04  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk4   WARNING The orphaned sites could cause upgrade failures. Try detach and reattach the database which contains the orphaned sites. Restart upgrade if necessary.  6dae5d9d-cc17-d003-e007-3995887e71c6
02/10/2016 01:10:16.76  OWSTIMER (0x0D64)   0x0C04  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk3   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content  6dae5d9d-cc17-d003-e007-3995887e71c6
02/10/2016 01:10:16.76  OWSTIMER (0x0D64)   0x0C04  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk3   ERROR   Database [WSS_Content] contains a site (Id = [016ffbd0-7d5a-469d-83c5-e9b67dbb2ba3], Url = [/kb/customerservice]) whose url is already used by a different site, in database (Id = [2611b773-88bc-4cc8-bebb-aa3cd238bc22], name = [WSS_Content]), in the same web application. Consider deleting one of the sites which have conflicting urls.  6dae5d9d-cc17-d003-e007-3995887e71c6
02/10/2016 01:10:16.82  OWSTIMER (0x0D64)   0x0C04  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk4   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content  6dae5d9d-cc17-d003-e007-3995887e71c6
02/10/2016 01:10:16.82  OWSTIMER (0x0D64)   0x0C04  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk4   WARNING The orphaned sites could cause upgrade failures. Try detach and reattach the database which contains the orphaned sites. Restart upgrade if necessary.  6dae5d9d-cc17-d003-e007-3995887e71c6
Timestamp               Process                                     TID     Area                            Category                        EventID Level       Message     Correlation
02/10/2016 01:14:24.26  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxmn   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=SharePoint_AdminContent_e44bfe21-eac4-48b... 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:14:24.26  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxmn   WARNING Exception occured when querying old feature with id [427741e7-6206-48ff-9f4c-53ffddda7f7d], skipping. Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Failed to find the XML file at location '15\Template\Features\Bamboo.SPWiki\feature.xml'     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPXmlDocCache.GetGlobalXmlDocument(String pathTemplateRelativeXml, SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Int32 compatibilityLevel)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarmFeatureDefinitionContext.LoadFileAsXmlDocument(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, String featureRelativePath)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_Scope()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.PopulateFeaturesTable(StringBuilder sqlstr) 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:14:52.09  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxkz   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:14:52.09  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxkz   ERROR   Database [WSS_Content] contains a site (Id = [70293d27-db5b-4f14-a2a7-cf089ffaf573], Url = [/kb/CustomerServiceKB]) that is not found in the site map. Consider detach and reattach the database.   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:14:52.09  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk0   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:14:52.09  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk0   WARNING The orphaned sites could cause upgrade failures. Try detach and reattach the database which contains the orphaned sites. Restart upgrade if necessary.  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:14:52.09  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxkz   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:14:52.09  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxkz   ERROR   Database [WSS_Content] contains a site (Id = [016ffbd0-7d5a-469d-83c5-e9b67dbb2ba3], Url = [/kb/customerservice]) that is not found in the site map. Consider detach and reattach the database. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:14:52.09  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk0   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:14:52.09  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk0   WARNING The orphaned sites could cause upgrade failures. Try detach and reattach the database which contains the orphaned sites. Restart upgrade if necessary.  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:14:52.09  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk3   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:14:52.09  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk3   ERROR   Database [WSS_Content] contains a site (Id = [70293d27-db5b-4f14-a2a7-cf089ffaf573], Url = [/kb/CustomerServiceKB]) whose url is already used by a different site, in database (Id = [2611b773-88bc-4cc8-bebb-aa3cd238bc22], name = [WSS_Content]), in the same web application. Consider deleting one of the sites which have conflicting urls.    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:14:52.09  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk4   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:14:52.09  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk4   WARNING The orphaned sites could cause upgrade failures. Try detach and reattach the database which contains the orphaned sites. Restart upgrade if necessary.  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:14:52.09  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk3   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:14:52.09  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk3   ERROR   Database [WSS_Content] contains a site (Id = [016ffbd0-7d5a-469d-83c5-e9b67dbb2ba3], Url = [/kb/customerservice]) whose url is already used by a different site, in database (Id = [2611b773-88bc-4cc8-bebb-aa3cd238bc22], name = [WSS_Content]), in the same web application. Consider deleting one of the sites which have conflicting urls.  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:14:52.09  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk4   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:14:52.09  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentDatabaseSequence   ajxk4   WARNING The orphaned sites could cause upgrade failures. Try detach and reattach the database which contains the orphaned sites. Restart upgrade if necessary.  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:15:02.05  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxnm   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:15:02.05  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxnm   ERROR   Upgrade [SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content] failed.    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:15:02.07  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxnm   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:15:02.07  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxnm   ERROR   Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:15:02.08  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxnm   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
02/10/2016 01:15:02.08  PSCONFIG (0x1E64)   0x167C  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxnm   ERROR      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseIntegrity.CheckAppOrphans()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseIntegrity.Check(SPContentDatabaseIntegrityCheckOptions options)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence.ContentDatabaseDataIntegrityCheck()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence.PreUpgrade()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

so i am trying to remove the orphans site collections , using the following command:-

```
$ContentDBColl = Get-SPContentDatabase
ForEach ($Database in $ContentDBColl)
{
   Write-Host "Detecting Orphans for " $Database.Name
   $Database.Repair($true)
}
```

but i got the following error:-

> Exception calling "Repair" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid object name
>   'TVF_AllDocs_DelIdUrl'. Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a
>   mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0,
>   current count = 1." At line:4 char:4
>   +    $Database.Repair($true)
>   +    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException

as follow:-
[image]

so can anyone advice on this please? 
Thanks

**EDIT**
now i try removing the orphan site collection as follow:-

```
stsadm -o deletesite -force   -siteid 016ffbd0-7d5a-46
9d-83c5-e9b67dbb2ba3   -databasename WSS_Content  -databaseserver t***1\sha
repoint
```

but it raised the following exception:-

> Invalid object name 'TVF_Sites_Id'. The 'proc_DeleteSite' procedure
>   attempted to return a status of NULL, which is n ot allowed. A status
>   of 0 will be returned instead.

Answer (score 1):

Typically when these types of errors occur, it is best to abandon the Content Database. Create a new Content Database on the Web Application, then use `Move-SPSite` to migrate each Site Collection to the new database. Once you've migrated to the new Content Database, perform an `iisreset`, then detach the old Content Database.

Comment: so can you please specify the commands to do so ? or describe in more details the required steps in general ?

Comment: More information about `Move-SPSite` can be found at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607915.aspx. The cmdlet is simple: `Move-SPSite http://siteUrl -DestinationDatabase NewDatabase`

Comment: ok thanks ,, but now i use to have 8 site collections inside the content database, but after i dismount and mount the content database , i see 11 site collections under the content database.. the additional 3 site collection are old sites that i have removed (orphands) so do i need to move all the site collection to the new content database ? inclining  orphans ?can u please adivce?

Comment: Why would you move the orphans? Just move what you're using.

Comment: because when i dismount and mount the content database trying to fix my problem, i went to "Central administration >> view all site collections" i see 11 site collections (8 valid & 3 orphans)... also when i check "Central administration>>manage content database" it mentioned that the content database have 11 site collections...

Comment: Right, but why would you migrate what you're not using? Just migrate the Site Collections you need.

Comment: this is valid but i wanted to check, i will try your steps now ,, thanks

Comment: now i create a new content database, then i try moving one of the sote collections , but i got this exception "Move-SPSite : Cannot complete the copy or merge operation because the database
schema versions are different.
At line:1 char:1"

Comment: Ah you're stuck. I'd suggest you create a PSS case with Microsoft as they may give you what are otherwise unsupported methods to fix the issue.

Comment: so there are not ny thing to do from my side?

Answer (score 0):

I had Orphaned sites after running Move_SPSite.
The solution for me was found on [this webpage](http://sharepoint-mattharmon.blogspot.com/2015/09/deleting-orphaned-sites-from-sharepoint.html).

To summarise, get the orphaned site ID by running this command on the SharePoint Server:

```
stsadm -o enumallwebs -DatabaseName "ContentDB_Name"
```

Then:

```
stsadm -o deletesite -force -SiteID **ORPHANED SITE ID** -DatebaseName "ContentDB_NAME" -DatabaseServer "SQL_Server"
```